# delete look up reference

Tags: soql, lookup

I have two objects A and B. I have a look up reference of B on A. 
In certain cases, if the A has B reference, I would want to delete the look up it by making it null or blank, so that I can look up a new B reference on A.

How do I achieve this using soql query?

Thanks,
P

Comment: I tried.. A.B__c = ''; update A; looks like this doesn't work.. It says invalid ID..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment, change

```
A.B__c = ''; 
update A;
```

to

```
A.B__c = null;
update A;
```

'' is an empty string, rather than a null value which is what you need to clear a lookup.